# traversing string in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, substring, performance

I have a number of strings concatenated together

```
"[thing 1,thing 2,cat in the hat,Dr. Suese]"
```

I would like to traverse this string to stop at a specific comma (given an index) and return the substring immediately after the comma and before the next comma. The problem is I need to do it in JavaScript. I assume it would be something like this

```
function returnSubstring(i,theString){
    var j,k = 0;
    while(theString.charCodeAt(k) != ','){
        while(i > 0){
            if (theString.charCodeAt(j) == ','){
                i--;
            }
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    return theString.substring(j,k);
}
```

Is this what it should look like or is there some syntax issue here

Comment: Can your data only come in this format? Why not use JSON to serialize the data?

Comment: Do you mean the index of the comma among commas (i.e. the second comma) or the index of the comma in the string (i.e the first comma after the twentieth char) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to traverse this string to stop at a specific comma (given an index) and return the substring immediately after the comma and before the next comma.

--> Let's assume specific index for comma accpeted is 8 i.e. first comma index, you can do :

```
var givenCommaIndex = 8;
var value = "[thing 1,thing 2,cat in the hat,Dr. Suese]";
var subString = value.substring(givenCommaIndex+1, value.indexOf(",", givenCommaIndex+1));
console.log(subString);

// Output :
"thing 2"
```

I can write the reusable function like below, it will not just work for comma but other delimiters as well :

```
function getSubString(str, delimiter, indexOfDelimiter) {
    // TODO : handle specific cases like str is undefined or delimiter is null
    return str.substring(indexOfDelimiter+1, str.indexOf(delimiter, indexOfDelimiter+1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) :

```
var token = "[thing 1,thing 2,cat in the hat,Dr. Suese]"
    .slice(1,-1) // remove [ and ]
    .split(',')
    [2]; // the third token
```

Or use a regular expression :

```
var token = "[thing 1,thing 2,cat in the hat,Dr. Suese]"
    .match(/([^\]\[,]+)/g)
    [2];
```

Comment: He wants to input the index of the comma.

Comment: @thefourtheye This isn't clear for me. I added a question in comment.

Comment: @thefoureye my bad. one off mistake. `(j+1,j+k-1)` i think